# Impossible to fetch data from a json file into php variable

Tags: php, json, curl, json-deserialization

I'm using Giscloud's REST API to grab a json with some info that i need for my web app. The problem is that it seems impossible that I can fetch and/or decode any data from that json using the corresponding php functions. I think it has something to do with the way the json file is structured.

This is the json file (some fields edited):

```
{
  "type": "maps",
  "total": 3,
  "page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "edited",
      "name": "Mapa de Mantención en Linea",
      "owner": "edited",
      "epsg": "900913",
      "active": "1",
      "copyright": "",
      "proj4": "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs",
      "units": "meter",
      "maxzoom": "0",
      "mobileacess": "f",
      "bgcolor": "#417893",
      "wmsaccess": null,
      "modified": 1483563460,
      "accessed": 1483563460,
      "created": 1483021672,
      "description": "",
      "maptype": null,
      "assets": null,
      "rating": "0",
      "units_proj4": "meter",
      "visited": "31",
      "resource_id": "6102219",
      "measure_unit": "meter",
      "share": "f",
      "bounds": "    {\"xmin\":-8027875.3326789,\"xmax\":-7742459.4690621,\"ymin\":-4065685.5344885,\"ymax\":-3929474.7500843}"
    },
    {
      "id": "edited",
      "name": "Mapa de Operaciones",
      "owner": "edited",
      "epsg": "900913",
      "active": "1",
      "copyright": "",
      "proj4": "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs",
      "units": "meter",
      "maxzoom": "0",
      "mobileacess": "f",
      "bgcolor": "#417893",
      "wmsaccess": null,
      "modified": 1483563473,
      "accessed": 1483563473,
      "created": 1483021672,
      "description": "",
      "maptype": null,
      "assets": null,
      "rating": "0",
      "units_proj4": "meter",
      "visited": "45",
      "resource_id": "6102603",
      "measure_unit": "meter",
      "share": "f",
      "bounds": "{\"xmin\":-8027263.8364526,\"xmax\":-7741847.9728358,\"ymin\":-4075469.474109,\"ymax\":-3939258.6897048}"
    },
    {
      "id": "edited",
      "name": "Mapa M&IC",
      "owner": "edited",
      "epsg": "900913",
      "active": "1",
      "copyright": "",
      "proj4": "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs",
      "units": "meter",
      "maxzoom": "0",
      "mobileacess": "f",
      "bgcolor": "#417893",
      "wmsaccess": null,
      "modified": 1483563449,
      "accessed": 1483563449,
      "created": 1483021672,
      "description": "",
      "maptype": null,
      "assets": null,
      "rating": "0",
      "units_proj4": "meter",
      "visited": "35",
      "resource_id": "6102604",
      "measure_unit": "meter",
      "share": "f",
      "bounds": "{\"xmin\":-8028181.080792,\"xmax\":-7742765.2171752,\"ymin\":-4074552.2297696,\"ymax\":-3938341.4453654}"
    }
  ]
}
```

These are the different ways that i've tried to decode this json and put it into a variable.

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);

// Number 1
$data = var_dump(json_decode($json));
echo $data['data'][0]['id'];
exit;

// Number 1 returns
object(stdClass)[21]
    public 'code' => string 'FATAL' (length=5)
    public 'msg' => string 'Internal error' (length=14)

// Number 2
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data['data'][0]['id'];

// Number 2 returns
PHP Undefined index: data
```

I've tried several other similar functions, like print_r. Or change some values there and here, but nothing has worked.

I would appreciate a lot some help on this!

Some extra info:

1. There's no problem with curl. It executes correctly.
2. Yes, the server answers with a json file.

UPDATE

1. Using `json_last_error()` (no need of parameters) I was able to debbug. The function returns an int depending of the type of error. Mine was `0`meaning that there's no error.
2. I think I ran out of ideas for this.

Comment: The JSON String validates ( using `jsonlint.com` )

Comment: Your code returns 'edited' for me, which is correct.

Comment: you are decoding to a StdClass , but using the object as an associative array ... json_decode defaults to stdClass : see **[the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loose the `var_dump()` thats just for debugging and it is stoppping the `json_decode()` from returning a PHP Object from the `json_decode()`.

Then use the correct object syntax to address the object

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($json);
// debug code
if ( json_last_error() > 0) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
} else
    // this should print the data structure
    print_r($data);
}
// end debug code

echo $data->data[0]->id;
```

If you want all the `id`'s from all the occurances you can do

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data->data as $idx => $obj ){
    echo "Occurance $idx = " . $obj->id;
}
```

Comment: I tried with your first example. It throws me this error:
`Undefined property: stdClass::$data`

Seems to me that the `json_decode()` does something with the object properties in the json in the proccess, like modify their name or something, because when echoing the value I want seems to have no clue that that value exists.

Comment: BTW: I'm using WAMP Server, and since you're a Wamp user too ¿couldn't be a missing php extension?

Comment: No `json_*` functions are in the Core I believe

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using? And what version of PHP

Comment: Although `php_curl` is optional Do you have 'php_curl` and `php_openssl` activated?

Comment: I added a bit of debug code to the first part of my answer. Try with that and see if it shows any issues

Comment: I just ran both bits of code, using the JSON String you gave in your question and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Object syntax:**

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$json_data = json_decode($json);

foreach ( $json_data->data as $data_item){
  echo '<p>ID: ' . $data_item->id . ' -- Name: ' . $data_item->name . '</p>';
  }
```

**Array Syntax:**

Get the data as an associated array by adding a second parameter TRUE to json_decode() [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$data_array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ( $data_array['data'] as $item){
  echo '<p>ID: ' . $item['id'] . ' -- Name: ' . $item['name'] . '</p>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont preferable to use cURL In this situation , you can use

```
file_get_contents
```

so here is a simple code

```
$userdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("JSON_URL_GOES_HERE"), true)
$u_ID = $userdata['data'][0]['id'];
```

and so on
see :[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: I need to use cURL. I have an API Key.

Comment: you can use full url with your api key and get the same data , it's easy !!